# iTerm2 jump forward slashes

Tags: terminal, binding, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2

What binding do I need to setup so I can jump to each forward slash in a path in iTerm2? I'm using a mac with BigSur.

Currently, I have my binding set up so it will skip by word. In the example below, if the cursor is at the end of the path (after the 'h'), and I hit option + left arrow, it will jump to colon after 's3'. I want it to jump to the '/' after 'file' and before 'path'.

```
s3://my-bucket/my/file/path
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tl;dr: add two lines to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

It looks like this is a matter of Mac switching to zsh from bash. I had this same problem -- slashes were treated as word breaks on my old MBP, but not on a newer one, and altering key mappings to various Escape sequences or Hex codes didn't seem to change anything.

Credit goes to the first two commenters [on this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223669/117890). The answer itself just provides the hex codes for deleting word-wise, but using this zsh setting instantly fixed the forward/backward cursor movement for me, including slashes as word breaks (as they should be!).

Comment: This is gold. Thank you so much for helping me with this one.